No such module 'AzureCommunicationCalling'
I'm using Microsoft Azure Communication Calling in my project. When the pod version is set to 2.7.0, it works fine. However, the issue is that this version has a notification that expires in 24 hours, which I don't want. I checked the latest SDK and found that it allows setting the notification expiration time to 180 days. So, I decided to change the SDK version from 2.7.0 to 2.9.0. After running pod install, I encountered the error "No such module 'AzureCommunicationCalling'" when importing. I've tried several solutions:

Cleared the project

Deleted derived data

Restarted my Mac and Xcode

Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No"

Set Swift language version to 5.0

Selected the pod schema and tried building; it succeeded, so I switched back to the project schema, but the same issue occurred

Added a script in the Podfile to change all the SDKs to Swift version 5.0


